# Bootstrap3.0 full screen

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I can't understand how I can remove this "block" who it appears in the lower part of view, it's outside of html, this is a screen:

[image]

this is jsp page:

```
<head>
    <title><spring:message code="message.title" /> :: <spring:message code="message.subtitle" /></title>
    <jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/view/head-common.jsp" />

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
             <!-- <div class="row-height"> -->
                <div class=".col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 .col-lg-8" >
                  <div id="viewer" style="height: 1000px; !important;"></div>
                </div>
            <!-- </div> -->
        </div>
    </div> 
</body>
```

Soma advice?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you adding dots to the classes `.col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 .col-lg-8` ?

Comment: I found it from web example, do you think that might be the error?

Comment: maybe, change code to this `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-8" >`

Comment: Ok thx, I'll try soon

Comment: no, always same problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<head>
    <title><spring:message code="message.title" /> :: <spring:message code="message.subtitle" /></title>
    <jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/view/head-common.jsp" />
    <style>
    html, body{
        height:100%;
    }
    </style>
</head>


<body>
<div class="container" style="height:100%;">
     <div class="row" style="height:100%;">
         <!-- <div class="row-height"> -->
            <div class=".col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 .col-lg-8"  style="height:100%;">
              <div id="viewer" style="height: 100%; !important; border:1px solid;">
              this he here
              </div>
            </div>
        <!-- </div> -->
    </div>
</div> 
</body>
```

Comment: Ok it might be resolved, but height: 100%; doesn't nwork, instead height: 1000px works, Why?

Comment: Or better, on container height: 100% doesn't work, but if I use: on container height:10000px and on row height:100% works